# Is it possible to use SignalR on aspnetcore 3.1 without the new EndpointRouting system?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Title is the question.
I am wondering because I want to also use Odata, which does not yet support endpoint routing.

Comment: I have not figured out how to make it work. Any news from your effort?

Comment: @flipdoubt unfortunatly not

Answer (score -1):

This works for us. In **Startup.Configure**, disable endpoint routing with `services.AddControllers(mvcOptions => mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false)`. In **Startup.ConfigureServices**, you can still use `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapHub<SignalRHub>("/SignalRHub"))` even though endpoint routing is enabled.